# Issue while printing in HTML

Tags: html, css, angular, angularjs-directive

I am getting an array of users in response and there is one more array of roles in that respose and I want to print that role in my HTML.

### Response :

```
User
email : "musaevt@yahoo.com"
firstName : "Timur"
fullName : "Timur Musaev"
id : "auth0|5a1ff162a916760a80b8b838"
lastName : "Musaev"
roles : Array(2)
0 : "Student"
1 : "Guest"
```

---

HTML :

---

```
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of users
              | hipUsersSorter: key: direction
              | paginate: { id: 'server', itemsPerPage: usersPerPage, currentPage: currentPage, total: totalUsers }">    
      <td>{{ user.lastName }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.firstName }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
      <td *ngFor ="let role of user.roles" >
        {{ role | translate }}
      </td>
      <td>
        <button md-icon-button color="primary" [routerLink]="[ '/users/edit-user', user.id ]">
          <md-icon>edit</md-icon>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

---

I am able to print this but because of 2 values in roles array, it is creating a new column and alignment gets changed. How can i print those two roles without changing the alignment of my edit button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about not looping on the td, but rather create a looping span inside the td?

```
<td>
    <span *ngFor ="let role of user.roles" >
    {{ role | translate }}
    </span>
  </td>
```

Here's the full HTML code:

```
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let user of users
          | hipUsersSorter: key: direction
          | paginate: { id: 'server', itemsPerPage: usersPerPage, currentPage: currentPage, total: totalUsers }">    
  <td>{{ user.lastName }}</td>
  <td>{{ user.firstName }}</td>
  <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
  <td>
    <span *ngFor ="let role of user.roles" >
    {{ role | translate }}
    </span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <button md-icon-button color="primary" [routerLink]="[ '/users/edit-user', user.id ]">
      <md-icon>edit</md-icon>
    </button>
  </td>
</tr>
```